# ClassNotFoundException / NoClassDefFoundError for jakarta.json.bind types in quarkus

Tags: jakarta-ee, classnotfoundexception, noclassdeffounderror, jsonb, quarkus

I have a maven module that depends on / uses types from `jakarta.json.bind`. However these types can not be resolved out of the box in latest quarkus (1.13.0.Final). Is there a recommended way to make using types from `jakarta.json.bind` possible in quarkus?

Adding a dependency to jakarta.json.bind-api does not help and seems to cause other problems:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.json.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.json.bind-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quarkus doesn't use the jakarta packages currently.

To use JSON-B in Quarkus you should use

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-jsonb</artifactId>
    <version>1.13.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanx for the clarification. However, it will take some time to provide a "backward compatibility layer" for my application. I hoped to be on the most up to date track with quarkus ...

I'll accept this answer as soon as I finished work on the compatibility layer and I can run some tests (may take some days, it is spare time stuff).

Meanwhile, why is it that some of the official quarkus components already use the jakarta namespace (e.g. quarkus-resteasy-jsonb 1.13.0)?

Thanx again.

Comment: Quarkus has not yet moved any of its extensions to the jakarta namespace

Comment: As far as I can see in 1.13.0.Final quite a fex quarkus extensions pull in jakarta packages already (quarkus-resteasy-jsonb for example).

Anyway, thanx again for your answer which made me kick out all jakarta dependencies I pulled in myself and that finally seems to solve my issue. Therefore: answer accepted.

Comment: Meanwhile, is there any (early adopter) support in quarkus 2.0 for jakarta namespace (and especially jakarta.persistence) and hibernate JPA?

Comment: No, there is not

Comment: Is there any timeplan for that?